# Follow Up For: I have 2 radio buttons and i want to make a different ajax page load into a div element depending on which one is selected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the script working on nearly all devices. However, The Issue I am having is that the JavaScript doesn't work on an iPad 2, I need to allow this to work on an iPad 2, Either that or some other version of the script that detects that it is on an iPad 2 and uses a different script because of that.

This is the script I am using currently that doesn't support iPad 2:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let location_one = document.getElementById('location1');
            let location_two = document.getElementById('location2');
            
            let getLocationOneData = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'locationData1.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                    }
                });
            };
            
            let getLocationTwoData = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'locationData2.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                    }
                });
            };
            
            let getData = function () {
                if (location_one.checked) {
                    getLocationOneData();
                } else if (location_two.checked) {
                    getLocationTwoData();
                }
            }
            
            location_one.addEventListener('change', function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    getLocationOneData()
                }
            });
            
            location_two.addEventListener('change', function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    getLocationTwoData();
                }
            });
            getData();
            setInterval(function () {
                getData();
            }, 120000);  // it will refresh the data every 3 mins
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: For iPad (ios devices) , consider using drop down as an alternative.

Comment: It's not clear what goes wrong on an iPad. You didn't actually explain the problem

Comment: The issue isn't with the radio buttons, the issue is that the JavaScript doesn't work on the iPad

Comment: You'd make it easier for ppl to help if you create create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - with the **MINIMAL** HTML to be able to run the Javascript.  What browser/version are you using on the iPad?  What debugging have you tried?  For eg, can you see the AJAX requests happening from the PHP side?  Have you tried adding alerts etc so you can see what is happening on the iPad?

Comment: One of the original benefits of jQuery was it got around all the variations in JS implementations between browsers. That is much less of a problem now, but considering you're on an iPad 2 maybe that is relevant, as you are using a strange mix of jQuery and plain Javascript.  Have you tried just using jQuery?

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to turn that into JQuery 